# Additional product description tab magento

Tags: magento, tabs, product

I'm using magento 1.9.2.1. I need to add an additional product description tab in the product page such that the contents of each tabs will be different for different products. It should not be a common description such as the sizing guide or something. It should have different information based on the product.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Update layout:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="core/template" name="test.block" as="test" template="test/product/view/tab.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup">
                <group>detailed_info</group>
            </action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value">
                <value>Additional Description Tab</value>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Create template test/product/view/tab.phtml and add some code:

```
<?php
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
if ($product->getId()):
    echo $product->getAttributeText('is_featured');
endif;
```

Don't forget to replace test values (block type, name, template) with your personal values

Actually if you use the "rwd" theme.